Какой это член предложения и почему?
В предложении «Она была без ума от него» слово «от него» — это обстоятельство причины или дополнение?

Задай вопрос от нужного к нужному члену предложения.


Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка: Без ума, Экспрес. 1. от кого, от чего. В восторге, в восхищении.

Вопрос приведен  в словаре, и это вопрос для дополнения, но никак не обстоятельства.  Сравнить:  она восхищается им, она в восхищении от него. Он — не причина восхищения, а объект для восхищения.

Значение обстоятельства причины (почему?) можно увидеть в таком предложении:


„Женщины, бесспорно, умнее мужчин. Вряд ли найдется женщина, которая была бы без ума от мужчины только из-за его красивых ног.“ —  Марлен Дитрих немецкая и американская актриса и певица 1901–1992

Карта слов (примеры предложений)

Дамы всех возрастов были без ума (от чего, из-за чего?) от его дерзости и обаяния.
Здесь дополнение имеет сопутствующее значение обстоятельства. Объект обозначен притяжательным местоимением. Сравнить: Дамы всех возрастов были от него без ума из-за его дерзости и обаяния.
